# How can I join jsonb to jsonb using activerecord in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to join two table columns with jsonb datatypes. Here are some models with jsonb:

```
User.create(emails: ['foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar2.com'])

Email.create(
  to: [
    {email: 'foo@bar.com', name: 'foo bar'}, 
    {email: 'foo3@bar3.com', name: 'foo bar3'}
  ], 
  from: 'foobar@bar.com'
)
```

I have tried:

```
joins("LEFT JOIN emails ON (users.emails ? emails.from_email OR emails.to->'email') ?| users.emails")
```

And I get: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of OR must be type boolean, not type jsonb`

I have also tried using the `where` method instead:

```
email_addresses = User.last.pluck(:emails).flatten
emails = Email.where(
  "(to->'email' ?| :email_addresses OR from ?| :email_addresses)",
  email_addresses: email_addresses
)
```

And I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"`.  I assume this is because the column is an array of objects.. not sure how to get past the array part.

Comment: Your first join is the right approach, but your parentheses are mismatched. Try `joins("LEFT JOIN emails ON (users.emails ? emails.from_email OR emails.to->'email' ?| users.emails")` instead.

Comment: Whoops yea, that was a copy and paste error.  I also renamed "to" to "recipients" because I think that was causing issues.  I think at this point, I may just select `jsonb_array_elements(emails)` as a column

Comment: @RobertNubel Your comment is confusing, because *your* parentheses are mismatched in your suggestion.  You have two (( and only one ).

Comment: @PeterH.Boling matching parenthesis must be the third truly hard thing in computer science. `joins("LEFT JOIN emails ON (users.emails ? emails.from_email OR emails.to->'email' ?| users.emails)")`